# How to enable OpenGL extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader, opengl-extensions

I'm developing an Android app with OpenGL ES 2.0 and I'd like to use the **[GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) extension**.

From what I understand, I need to enable it first with the `#extension` directive at the top of my fragment shader, and then I can use the built-in variable `gl_LastFragData`.

So here is my fragment shader:

```
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- Enable the extension

varying highp vec2 textureCoords;
uniform sampler2D currentTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 currentColor = texture2D(currentTexture, textureCoords);
    gl_FragColor = currentColor;
}
```

However, when I compile the shader, I get the following compilation error:

```
Couldn't compile shader: Fragment shader compilation failed.
ERROR: 0:1: '' :     GLSL error: extension 'GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch' is not supported
ERROR: 1 compilation errors. No code generated.
```

The error is pretty explicit: **this extension is not** ***supported***.

My technical specs:

- **Hardware**: Samsung Galaxy S4
- **Android version**: 5.0.1
- **Android API level**: 21
- **OpenGL version** (`glGetString(GL_VERSION)`): OpenGL ES 3.0 V@84.0 AU@  (CL@)

I have a few questions:

- Is there anything I can do to **install** this extension on my device?
- If not, can I install it/use it on an **emulator**?
- Is it a *software* matter or really a *hardware* problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to install this extension on my device?

No; either the GPU and driver support it, or they don't.

> If not, can I install it/use it on an emulator?

If the emulator supports the extension, then yes you can use it ...

> Is it a software matter or really a hardware problem?

Could be either a limitation in the underlying hardware, or a limitation in the driver. From an app developer point of view the two are indivisible, so it's sort of irrelevant which is the limitation really ...