# How can I simulate "Glow Dodge" blending by using OpenGL Shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, blending

I wanted to simulate 'glow dodge' effect on clip studio using opengl and its shader.
So I found out that following equation is how 'glow dodge' works.

> ```
> final.rgb = dest.rgb / (1 - source.rgb)
> ```

Then I came up with 2 ways to actually do it, but neither one doesn't seem to work.

First one was to calculate `1 / (1 - source.rgb)` in the shader, and do multiply blending by using `glBlendfunc(GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_COLOR)`, or `glBlendfunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO)`.

but as khronos page says, all scale factors have range 0 to 1. which means I can't multiply the numbers over 1. so I can't use this method cuz most of the case goes more than 1.

Second one was to bring background texels by using `glReadPixel()`, then calculate everything in shader, then do additive blending by using `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.

regardless the outcome I could get, `glReadPixel()` itself takes way too much time even with a 30 x 30 texel area. so I can't use this method.

I wonder if there's any other way to get an outcome as glowdodge blending mode should have.

Answer (score 0):

With the extension [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) a value from the framebuffer can be read:

> This extension provides a mechanism whereby a fragment shader may read existing framebuffer data as input. This can be used to implement compositing operations that would have been inconvenient or impossible with fixed-function blending. It can also be used to apply a function to the framebuffer color, by writing a shader which uses the existing framebuffer color as its only input.

The extension is available for *dektop* OpenGL and OpenGL ES. An OpenGL extension has to be enabled (see [Core Language (GLSL)- Extensions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Extensions). The fragment color can be retrieved by the built in variable `gl_LastFragData`. e.g.:

```c
#version 400
#extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require

out vec4 fragColor;

# [...]

void main 
{
    # [...]

    fragColor = vec4(gl_LastFragData[0].rgb / (1.0 - source.rgb), 1.0);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer & editing the post. I tried to add "#extension ~~~ require" line as you said, but this error comes out. "error C0202: extension EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch not supported" I'm using GLFW 3.3.2 with visual studio. I wonder if this problem is caused by version mismatch.

Comment: @ApplePopsicle Sadly my solution does not work for you, because your hardware does not support the extension `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch`. See [How to enable OpenGL extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912060/how-to-enable-opengl-extension-gl-ext-shader-framebuffer-fetch-on-android)

Comment: In practice this extension will only be reliably available on mobile devices. Render-to-texture is a better plan for desktop.